# Script to pull html and completely de-relativise it. (single file offline)

Tags: python, parsing, web-applications, web, lxml

I am trying to learn python and also create a web utility. One task I am trying to accomplish is creating a single html file which can be run locally but link to everything it needs to look like the original web page. (if you are going to ask why i want this, its because it may act of a part of a utility i am creating, or if not, just for education) So i have two questions, a theoretical one and a practical one:

1) Is this, for visual (as opposed to functional) purposes, possible? Can a html page work offline while linking to everything it needs online? or if their something fundamental about having the html file itself execute on the web server which does not allow this to be possible? How far can I go with it?

2) I have started a python script which de-relativises (made that one up) linked elements on a html page, but I am a noob so most likely I missed some elements or attributes which would also link to outside resources. I have noticed after trying a few pages that the one in the code below does not work properly, their appears to be a .js file which is not linking correctly. (the first of many problems to come) Assuming the answer to my first question was at least a partial yes, can anyone help me fix the code for this website?

Thank you.

Update, I missed the script tag on this, but even after I added it it still does not work correctly.

```
import lxml
import sys
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
import urllib2
from urlparse import urljoin

site = "www.script-tutorials.com/advance-php-login-system-tutorial/"
output_filename = "output.html"

def download(site):
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+site)
    html_input = response.read()
    return html_input

def derealitivise(site, html_input):

    active_html = lxml.html.fromstring(html_input)

    for element in tags_to_derealitivise:

        for tag in active_html.xpath(str(element+"[@"+"src"+"]")):
            tag.attrib["src"] = urljoin("http://"+site, tag.attrib.get("src"))

        for tag in active_html.xpath(str(element+"[@"+"href"+"]")):
            tag.attrib["href"] = urljoin("http://"+site, tag.attrib.get("href"))

    return lxml.html.tostring(active_html)

active_html = ""
tags_to_derealitivise = ("//img", "//a", "//link", "//embed", "//audio", "//video", "//script")

print "downloading..."
active_html = download(site)

active_html = derealitivise(site, active_html)

print "writing file..."

output_file = open (output_filename, "w")
output_file.write(active_html)
output_file.close()
```

Furthermore, I could make the code more through by checking all of the elements...

It would look kind of like this, but I do not know the exact way to iterate through all of the elements. This is a seperate problem, and I will most likely figure it out by the time anyone responds...:

```
def derealitivise(site, html_input):

active_html = lxml.html.fromstring(html_input)

for element in active_html.xpath:

    for tag in active_html.xpath(str(element+"[@"+"src"+"]")):
        tag.attrib["src"] = urljoin("http://"+site, tag.attrib.get("src"))

    for tag in active_html.xpath(str(element+"[@"+"href"+"]")):
        tag.attrib["href"] = urljoin("http://"+site, tag.attrib.get("href"))

return lxml.html.tostring(active_html)
```

*update*

Thanks to Burhan Khalid's solution, which seemed too simple to be viable at first glance, I got it working. The code is so simple most of you will most likely not require it, but I will post it anyway incase it helps:

```
import lxml
import sys
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
import urllib2
from urlparse import urljoin

site = "www.script-tutorials.com/advance-php-login-system-tutorial/"
output_filename = "output.html"

def download(site):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    html_input = response.read()
    return html_input

def derealitivise(site, html_input):

    active_html = html_input.replace('<head>', '<head> <base href='+site+'>')

    return active_html
active_html = ""


print "downloading..."
active_html = download(site)

active_html = derealitivise(site, active_html)

print "writing file..."

output_file = open (output_filename, "w")
output_file.write(active_html)
output_file.close()
```

Despite all of this, and its great simplicity, the .js object running on the website I have listed in the script still will not load correctly. Does anyone know if this is possible to fix?

Comment: there are lots of web site downloaders out there

Comment: @thkang many web site downloaders work by downloading all of the files in the web directory or something similar so that you may access the website offline, while i am trying to make only the html file offline, while using the linked resources over the web. Secondly, I want to program it myself, as this is partly for educational purposes, so mainly using what someone else has done is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> while i am trying to make only the html file offline, while using the
>   linked resources over the web.

This is a two step process:

1. Copy the HTML file and save it to your local directory.
2. Add a [`BASE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag in the `HEAD` section, and point the `href` attribute of it to the absolute URL.

Since you want to learn how to do it yourself, I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

@Burhan has an easy answer using `<base href="...">` tag in the `<head>`, and it works as you have found out. I ran the script you posted, and the page downloaded fine. As you noticed, some of the JavaScript now fails. This can be for multiple reasons.

If you are opening the HTML file as a local `file:///` URL, the page may not work. Many browsers heavily sandbox local HTML files, not allowing them to perform network requests or examine local files.

The page may perform `XmlHTTPRequests` or other network operations to the remote site, which will be denied for cross domain scripting reasons. Looking in the JS console, I see the following errors for the script you posted:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.script-tutorials.com/menus.php?give=menu. Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Unfortunately, if you do not have control of `www.script-tutorials.com`, there is no easy way around this.

Comment: Interesting point out! The weird part is that I am allowed to load both "http://www.script-tutorials.com/menus.php?give=menu" and "http://www.script-tutorials.com/assets/logo.js" (the gears script) right from my browser. Maybe their is some mask I can use so that it reads any ip address except localhost when sending the http requests? Again this is just an educational question.

Comment: If a page with JavaScript is hosted at `http://foo.com/`, it can *only* make JavaScript requests (e.g. XMLHttpRequest) to other pages on `http://foo.com/`. Requests to `http://bar.com/` will fail with an error. This is for security reasons. Therefore, by taking the page from its real domain (www.script-tutorials.com) and serving it from a different domain, it can no longer make requests back to its 'real' domain. This is where the errors are coming from. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Ahh, I understand, so when you load from the browser its still really loading from inside the domain. Is their a way to know which elements this applies to? would it be all .js objects? I want to be able to download as little as possible while still being able to modify the html. If i knew which objects would give this cross domain error I could ajust the script to download them and set the path to local. This would then require overriding the <BASE> tag for all .js elements. Is that feasible? Thank you very much for the comments!

Comment: There is no easy way to automatically do this for any and all sites. You could potentially fix this just for `script-tutorials.com`, but you would need a custom solution for every site you wanted to work with.

Comment: well, How would I start to fix this for scrpt-tutorials? Could a python script try to download each element with some kind of localhost mask and find out which ones return an error and put them in a list? If the local html file has an absolute link of http://www.blabla.com/something.js, why should that work differently then putting "http://www.blabla.com/something.js" in your browser's nav bar? (which works for downloading the logo.js if you try it yourself) I really want to figure this out, but if you don't feel like it is worth it to you after a certain point, just say so and I will leave.

Comment: I think fixing this deserves a whole new question. It is too complicated and involved to answer in the comments here, unfortunately!